# Twilio NodeJS - Request through Proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, twilio

How do I specify proxy when using Twilio github library?

As a workaround I can manually make requests to twilio. Alternatively I can modify my local version of *./lib/RequestClient.js*:

```
var options = {
    timeout: opts.timeout || 30000,
    proxy: 'http://myproxy.com:8080', // <- My proxy override
    followRedirect: opts.allowRedirects || false,
    url: opts.uri,
    method: opts.method,
    headers: opts.headers,
    forever: opts.forever === false ? false : true,
  };
```

Looking at twilio code - that request is not looking for proxy options. It would be nice if Twilio modified their RequestClient to accept proxy options during initialization.

Thank you!

Comment: Our team ended up going with Plivo since their NodeJS package has official support for proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Yes the helper library doesn't directly support proxies at the moment. There are a few options you could do to get this solved.

**Option 1:**
The helper library is using the [`request`](https://npm.im/request) module under the hood. Aside of the `proxy` option there is another way to specify a proxy using environment variables. If `twilio` is the only thing that is using `request` in your code base, that might be an option. You can read more about that in the `request` documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables

**Option 2:**
The helper library allows you to specify your own `RequestClient`. It has to implement the same interface as the [`RequestClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/base/RequestClient.js) in `lib/base/RequestClient.js` of the helper library. The easiest way would be to copy that file, modify the [`options`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/base/RequestClient.js#L42) variable to have the `proxy` option and then pass it to the `Twilio` constructor:

```
const twilio = require('twilio');
const MyRequestClient = require('./path/to/your/MyRequestClient');

const client = twilio(
    'account_sid',
    'auth_token', 
    { httpClient: new MyRequestClient() })

// do your requests
```

I hope this helps. I also made sure to create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/336) to make sure that this is added in the long term as an option.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added to the Twilio SDK.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node/custom-http-clients-node#call-twilio-through-a-proxy-server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).